# Travis CI deploy JAR to Github master

Tags: github, deployment, travis-ci

Refs: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/ and http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/

I'm tring to deploy my JAR file to Github, but I don't want to create a tag every time.
I know it is not the correct behaviour, but I want to do this way if possible.

Building process is running fine, but when I use this `travis.yml` file:

```
language: java
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api-key: "<my_api_key>"
  file: "teapot-1.2.5-beta.jar"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: master
```

I got this error:

```
Installing deploy dependencies
Fetching: addressable-2.3.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed addressable-2.3.6
Fetching: multipart-post-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multipart-post-2.0.0
Fetching: faraday-0.9.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed faraday-0.9.1
Fetching: sawyer-0.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sawyer-0.6.0
Fetching: octokit-3.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed octokit-3.7.0
5 gems installed
Fetching: mime-types-2.4.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-2.4.3
1 gem installed dpl.2
Preparing deploy
Logged in as Carlos Magno Oliveira de Abreu

Deploying to repo: icemagno/teapot
Current tag is: dpl.3
Deploying application
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/octokit-3.7.0/lib/octokit/response/raise_error.rb:16:in `on_complete': POST https://api.github.com/repos/icemagno/teapot/releases: 422 - Validation Failed (Octokit::UnprocessableEntity)
Error summary:
resource: Release
code: missing_field
field: tag_name
resource: Release
code: custom
field: tag_name
message: tag_name is not well-formed
resource: Release
code: custom
message: Published releases must have a valid tag // See: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release
...
failed to deploy
```

This is the basic deploy config:

```
language: java

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api-key: "<my_key_again>"
  file: "teapot-1.2.5-beta.jar"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

But I have not created any tag because I don't want to do this for now.

**EDIT**

I've created a tag, now I need to change `.travis.yml` file to test some configurations and GitHub is not allowing me to change anything on tag files (ok, must be this way) cr#p !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may, I believe what you are looking for is the same as [I was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217556/travis-ci-auto-tag-build-for-github-release).

Basically add something like the following to your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_deploy:
  - git config --global user.email "builds@travis-ci.com"
  - git config --global user.name "Travis CI"
  - export GIT_TAG=$TRAVIS_BRANCH-v0.1.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
  - git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "Generated tag from TravisCI for build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
  - git push -q https://<your-api-key>@github.com/<your_name>/<project_name> --tags

deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [redacted]
  file:
    - "your_file"
  on:
    tags: false
    all_branches: true

branches:
  except:
    - /^*-v[0-9]/
```

Careful doing this though, as messing up while working with these particular config options might lead to an infinite Travis-CI build loop, which will pollute your build and tag history, and not be easy to cleanup.

Comment: Thanks. Please tell me more about how can I mess this up.

Comment: If yous set on.tags: true, then every time you push, it adds the build tag which triggers another build, thus looping.

Comment: Ah! understood. I think you should write this in bold warning in your answer.

Comment: Please tell me more about `branches: except:` regex.

Comment: That is another check that I was using to filter out the tagged branches from being built. It just ignores the `branch-v[release number]` for added security.

Comment: Am I missing something or should the GIT_TAG have a 'v' after `BRANCH-` and before the digit `0`? i.e `GIT_TAG=$TRAVIS_BRANCH-v0.1.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER` in order to satisfy the branches except regex?

Comment: Yes, you would be correct. (Or at least I believe so...)