# Read versionName from build.gradle in bash

Tags: android, bash, gradle, travis-ci

Is there a way to read the value `versionName` from the `build.gradle` file of an Android project to use it in bash?

More precisely: How can I read this value from the file and use it in a Travis-CI script? I'll use it like

```
# ANDROID_VERSION=???
export GIT_TAG=build-$ANDROID_VERSION
```

I set up a Travis-CI like described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28230711/1700776.

My build.gradle: http://pastebin.com/uiJ0LCSk

Comment: grep "versionName"  build.gradle | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: Thank you - it works! Actually the file is in ``./app/build.gradle`` so the resulting ``.travis.yml`` line is ``- export VERSION=$(grep "versionName" ./app/build.gradle | awk '{print $2}')``

Comment: This will not work in all cases.  What if there are build variants that have different version names?  What if the build.gradle uses versionNameSuffix to modify version names per flavor?

Comment: As a workaround you can get versionCode from the apk when it will be ready: https://gist.github.com/j796160836/6ad39ba143bf038bfde8

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Expanding on Khozzy's answer, to retrieve versionName of your Android package from the build.gradle, add this custom task:

```
task printVersionName {
    doLast {
        println android.defaultConfig.versionName
    }
}
```

and invoke it so:

```
gradle -q printVersionName
```

Comment: ./gradlew -q printVersionName

Answer (score 16):

You can define a custom task, i.e.

```
task printVersion {
    doLast {
        println project.version
    }
}
```

And execute it in Bash:

```
$ gradle -q pV
1.8.5
```

Comment: this prints "unspecified" in my project.

Comment: @dan replace "project.version" with "android.defaultConfig.versionName"

Comment: I don't understand this answer. How is the task being called?

Comment: @Jim take a look at Gradle Task Abbreviation - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:task_name_abbreviation

Answer (score 10):

I like this one liner to get only the version name without quotes:

```
grep "versionName" app/build.gradle | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d \''"\'
```

Comment: It will not work for case when there are few flavors or different versions for different build variants.

Comment: Thanks, I added an additional param to get a clean version name: ```grep -m1 "versionName" app/build.gradle | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d \''"\'```

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to [alnet's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475432/read-versionname-from-build-gradle-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment58645220_35475432) comment I came up with this solution (note [Doug Stevenson's objection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475432/read-versionname-from-build-gradle-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment58646551_35475432)):

```
# variables
export GRADLE_PATH=./app/build.gradle   # path to the gradle file
export GRADLE_FIELD="versionName"   # field name
# logic
export VERSION_TMP=$(grep $GRADLE_FIELD $GRADLE_PATH | awk '{print $2}')    # get value versionName"0.1.0"
export VERSION=$(echo $VERSION_TMP | sed -e 's/^"//'  -e 's/"$//')  # remove quotes 0.1.0
export GIT_TAG=$TRAVIS_BRANCH-$VERSION.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
# result
echo gradle version: $VERSION
echo release tag: $GIT_TAG
```

Comment: It will not work for case when there are few flavors or different versions for different build variants.

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
grep -o "versionCode\s\+\d\+" app/build.gradle | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

The `-o` option makes grep only print the matching part so you're guaranteed that what you pass to `awk` is only the pattern `versionCode NUMBER`.

Comment: It will not work for case when there are few flavors or different versions for different build variants.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple flavors and set the version information in the flavor, you can use something like this:

```
task printVersion{
doLast {
    android.productFlavors.all {
        flavor ->
            if (flavorName.matches(flavor.name)) {
                print flavor.versionName + "-" + flavor.versionCode
            }
    }
}
}
```

You can then call it using

```
./gradlew -q printVersion -PflavorName=MyFlavor
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeking a migrated version for Kotlin DSL, here is with what I came up:

```
tasks.create("printVersionName") {
    doLast { println(version) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**eg**

```
android{
  android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        def fileName
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            if (!outputFile.name.contains('unaligned')) {
                fileName = "yourAppRootName_${variant.productFlavors[0].name}_${getVersionName()}_${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent + "/aligned", fileName)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

use `${getVersionName()}` to get version in build.gradle

Comment: Somehow [alnets'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475432/read-versionname-from-build-gradle-in-bash/35475826#comment58645220_35475432) very short solution works.

Answer (score 1):

grep versionName :

**For MAC** :

`grep -o "versionName\s.*\d.\d.\d" app/build.gradle | awk '{ print $2 }' | tr -d \''"\'`

**For Unbuntu** :

`grep -o "versionName\s\+.*" app/build.gradle | awk '{ print $2 }' | tr -d \''"\'`

So input in build.gradle `versionName "8.1.9"` give me `8.1.9`

Comment: This is the only answer working for versionName (without using gradle), thank you

Comment: It will not work for case when there are few flavors or different versions for different build variants.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a `gradle.properties` file.

1. Set your value in `gradle.properties`

```
VERSION_NAME=1.0 with more
```

2. Update your `gradle.build` to get the value from the `gradle.properties`

```
versionName VERSION_NAME
```

3. grep your `gradle.properties` file rather than `gradle.build`

```bash
grep "VERSION_NAME" app/gradle.properties | cut -d "=" -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a kotlin based buildfile (`build.gradle.kts`) you could solve it like this:

```bash
grep -o -E 'versionName = "[[:digit:]\.]+"' app/build.gradle.kts | grep -o -E '[[:digit:]\.]+'
```

I prefer Grep over Gradle, because Gradle is sooooo slow. (At least in my CD pipeline.)

## Whats going on in detail?

Grep is a common Posix utility to search for specific lines in text files. However it can do some pretty neat things.

`-o` returns only the matched text. 
`-E` makes Grep use advanced regex.

In step 1 we read the `build.gradle.kts` file and search for the line, that contains our version number.

```bash
grep -o -E 'versionName = "[[:digit:]\.]+"' app/build.gradle.kts
```

returns something like

```
versionName = "1.0"
```

In the next step we're piping this output to another grep's STDIN using a pipe symbol (`|`). There we match for the version number only. The regex `[[:digit:]\.]+` matches for one or more of these characters: `0123456789.` - which should be everything I expect to be in a version number.