# How to get version name from Android Gradle file in GitHub Actions?

Tags: android, github, github-actions

I have to create a release by using the create-release action provided by GitHub actions. The default config parameters in the build.gradle file like the following;

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and the action in the GitHub Actions yml file like the following;

```
- name: Create Release
    id: create_release
    uses: actions/create-release@v1
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    with:
      tag_name: <I need gradle version name here! It is 1.0>
      release_name: Release <I need gradle version name here! It is 1.0>
      body: |
        Release body
      draft: false
      prerelease: false
```

How can I get the gradle versionName in the GitHub Actions yml file to create a GitHub release?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read versionName from build.gradle in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475432/read-versionname-from-build-gradle-in-bash)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A path i took used gradle tasks.

In your module build.gradle, where version name is a simple ext property for gradle that you can set as a variable that can be used through out the gradle file.

```
task printVersionName {
  println project.ext.version_name
}
```

In your github actions .yaml file add these steps.

```
- name : Retrieve Version
  run: |
   echo "::set-output name=VERSION_NAME::$(${{github.workspace}}/gradlew -q printVersionName)"
  id: android_version
```

Following step is used to save it to a environmental variable that can be used through out the workflow file.

```
- name: Get version
  run: |
    echo "version_name=${{steps.android_version.outputs.VERSION_NAME}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

You can then reference the value through out your workflow file with

```
${{env.version_name}}
```

Comment: Correct Answer, This worked for me. I just logged In StackOverFlow to upvote this answer :)

Comment: It worked, but set-output is deprecated now, the suggested way is to use: 
echo "VERSION_NAME=$(${{github.workspace}}/gradlew -q printVersionName)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
and but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone help?

Comment: Getting error:
Unable to process file command 'output' successfully,
Invalid format 'Iterating variant: app-debug'

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can merge Retrieve and Get together as one.

```yaml
# Set VERSION_INFORMATION
- run: echo "VERSION_INFORMATION=$(${{github.workspace}}/gradlew -q printVersionInformation)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

For your `build.gradle(:app)`, we can use.

```
task printVersionInformation {
     println "v" + defaultConfig.versionName + " (" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ")"
}
```

Then, in your output. It remains the same.

```yaml
${{ env.VERSION_INFORMATION }}
```

Then, you should able to get the output of.

```
v1.0.0 (0)
```

Comment: For this to work i needed to add `android` in front of `defaultConfig` in the `printVersionInformation` task, so it's : `android.defaultConfig.versionName` and `android.defaultConfig.versionCode`